# cramming for the exams - what am i missing (C++ string manipulation)

Tags: c++, recursion, string

cramming for a c++ exam, on string manip with some example questions (to which i dont have solutions) - below is today's handiwork. although it works fine - would be awesome if any obvious lapses / better way of doing things occur to you, just drop me a quick note, i need to learn me some C++ fast :)

thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

//#include "words.h"

using namespace std;

void reverse(const char un_rev[], char rev[]);
void clean(const char in_string[], char out_string[]);
//produces 'cleaned' copy of the string and passes on to recursive compare
bool compare(const char input_1[], const char input_2[]);
//the recursive bit
bool compare_recur(char input_1[], char input_2[]);
bool palindrome(const char input[]);
//no mixed capps for func below!
int min_pos(int starting_pos, char input[]);
void sort(char input[]);
bool anagram(const char input_1[], const char input_2[]);



int main() {

  /*** QUESTION 1 ***/
  char reversed[9];
  reverse("lairepmi", reversed);
  cout << "'lairepmi' reversed is '" << reversed << "'" << endl;
  reverse("desserts", reversed);
  cout << "'desserts' reversed is '" << reversed << "'" << endl << endl;


  /*** QUESTION 2 **/
  cout << "The strings 'this, and THAT......' and 'THIS and THAT!!!' are ";
  if (!compare("this, and THAT......", "THIS and THAT!!!"))
    cout << "NOT ";
  cout << "the same" << endl << "  (ignoring punctuation and case)" << endl;

  cout << "The strings 'this, and THAT' and 'THIS, but not that' are ";
  if (!compare("this, and THAT", "THIS, but not that")) 
    cout << "NOT ";
  cout << "the same" << endl << "  (ignoring punctuation and case)" << endl << endl;

  /*** QUESTION 3 **/

  cout << "The string 'rotor' is ";
  if (!palindrome("rotor"))
    cout << "NOT ";
  cout << "a palindrome." << endl;

  cout << "The string 'Madam I'm adam' is ";
  if (!palindrome("Madam I'm adam"))
    cout << "NOT ";
  cout << "a palindrome." << endl;
  cout << "The string 'Madam I'm not adam' is ";
  if (!palindrome("Madam I'm not adam"))
    cout << "NOT ";
  cout << "a palindrome." << endl << endl;

  /*** QUESTION 4 **/

  cout << "The string 'I am a weakish speller!' is ";
  if (!anagram("I am a weakish speller!", "William Shakespeare"))
    cout << "NOT ";
  cout << "an anagram of 'William Shakespeare'" << endl;

  cout << "The string 'I am a good speller!' is ";
  if (!anagram("I am a good speller!", "William Shakespeare"))
    cout << "NOT ";
  cout << "an anagram of 'William Shakespeare'" << endl;

  return 0;
}



void reverse(const char* un_rev, char rev[]) {

  int len = 0;
  len = strlen(un_rev);
  int i = 0;

  rev[len+1] = '\0'; //null terminate string

  while (len >= 0) {
    rev[i] = un_rev[len -1];
    i++;
    len--;
  } 
}

void clean(const char in_string[], char out_string[]) {
  int n =0;

  for (int i = 0; in_string[i]; i++) {

    if (isalpha(in_string[i])) {
      out_string[n] = toupper(in_string[i]);
      n++;
    }
  }
  out_string[n] = '\0';
  //  cout << "out: " << out_string;
}


bool compare(const char input_1[], const char input_2[]) {

  //cleaned copies of string
  int len1 = strlen(input_1);
  int len2 = strlen(input_2);

  char cinput_1[len1+1];
  cinput_1[len1+1] = '\0';
  char cinput_2[len2+1];
  cinput_2[len2+1] = '\0';

  clean(input_1, cinput_1);
  clean(input_2, cinput_2);

  return(compare_recur(cinput_1, cinput_2));

}

//recursive bit of the compare function
//possibly work into a single func?
bool compare_recur(char input_1[], char input_2[]) {

  if (!(*input_1) || !(*input_2)) {
    return true;
  } else if ( *input_1 != *input_2) {
    return false;
  }

  return compare_recur(++input_1, ++input_2);

}


bool palindrome(const char input[]) {

  int len = strlen(input);

  char cinput[len+1];
  cinput[len+1] = '\0';

  reverse(input, cinput);
  compare(input, cinput);

}


int min_pos(int starting_pos, char input[]) {
  int min = starting_pos;
  char min_char = input[starting_pos];

  for (int i = starting_pos; input[i]; i++) {

    if (input[i] < min_char) {
      min = i;
      min_char = input[i];
    }
  }
  return min;
}


void sort(char input[]) {
  char temp;
  int the_min = 0;

  for(int i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
    the_min = min_pos(i, input);

    if ((the_min) != i) { 
      //swap
      temp = input[the_min];
      input[the_min] = input[i];
      input[i] = temp;

    }

  }
}


bool anagram(const char input_1[], const char input_2[]) {

  int len1 = strlen(input_1);
  int len2 = strlen(input_2);

  char cinput_1[len1+1];
  cinput_1[len1+1] = '\0';
  char cinput_2[len2+1];
  cinput_2[len2+1] = '\0';

  clean(input_1, cinput_1);
  clean(input_2, cinput_2);

  sort(cinput_1);
  sort(cinput_2);

  return compare(cinput_1, cinput_2);  

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use std::string instead of using C style string in C++

Comment: It looks like this is the assignment, by using C-style strings the OP has to implement this functionality.

Comment: Why are you getting rid of numerics in your clean function?

Comment: @sam they dont matter for purposes of this q.. 

although for this particular question you COULD theoretically use Cstring - for most that you have, you arent allowed, so i thought i better learn how to make these funcs.

Comment: @op You do realise that many of the above function declarations are not safe. There is not way for your function to know that the target array is big enough for the function output. This is the reason why the strcpy should also be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

As people have said, using std::string will make things much easier and safer. If you must use C-style strings, here is some critique of your code:

---

1. In many places you have code equivalent to

```
buf[len+1] = '\0';
```

This should be

```
buf[len] = '\0';
```

---

2. `palindrome` function doesn't return a value.

---

3. This code (variations of which appear in several places) is not standard C++, since the array size is not constant:

```
char cinput[len+1];
```

For variable-sized arrays, you need to allocate them dynamically:

```
char *cinput = new char[len+1];
//... use the array ...
delete[] cinput;
```

Of course, `std::string` or even `std::vector<char>` will make things easier here.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse a string:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sampleString("sample string");
    reverse(sampleString.begin(), sampleString.end());
    cout << "reverse:" << sampleString << endl;

}
```